# Android Studio - Error running MainActivity: Unknown run configuration type AndroidRunConfigurationType

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Everything was working fine a while ago, but then I started getting this error, which is really troubling:

[image: two muppets]
[image: three muppets]
[image: four muppets]
I just reinstalled Android studio and still showing me this issue.  Does anybody know what I can change to get a solid configuration back so I can run main activity?  The configuration windows give me little to work with.

Thanks in advance for any pointers
-T

Comment: maybe close the application and start it using `New > Import project` instead of `Open`

Comment: @ZeekHuge Didn't do it.  It seems that nothing is compiling, it's not importing any of my libraries.  What a drag :(

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.  There was a weird bug in the plugins section of preferences. Android support was unchecked and a couple of others simply needed to be toggled as they were red.  Scary.

Answer (score 0):

check your SDK if it's path is correctly set
if your laptop is Mac,check for JDK issues, openJDK have machine specific issues